# Get x and y coordinates from a specifically formatted text file into an Ordered dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, loops, ordereddictionary, read-text

I am trying to read a text file in a specific format and extract coordinates from them and store them in an ordered dict. One set in the text file consists of a title line followed by x and y coordinates. The x, y coordinates always start with `.` followed by `\t` (tab). One text file contains multiple such sets. My idea is to extract each of the sets' x and y into a list and append this to an ordered dict. Basically, in the end, it will be a list of lists with the number of lists being equal to the number of sets which will be appended to the ordered dict.

An illustration of how the text file looks like:

```
Freehand    green   2   2   0,0 289618  .   
.   104326.2,38323.8    104309.6,38307.2    104286.3,38287.3    104269.6,38270.6    104256.3,38254.0
.   104239.7,38237.4    104223.0,38220.7    104209.7,38204.1    104193.1,38194.1    104176.4,38187.5

Freehand    green   2   3   0,0 63980   .   
.   99803.4,37296.2 99826.7,37306.2 99843.3,37312.8 99860.0,37316.2 99876.6,37322.8
```

My code:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

dict_roi = OrderedDict([
                ("title", []),
                ("X", []),
                ("Y", []) ])

with open(elements_file,"r") as f:

    try:
        # pattern to match to get coordinates
        pattern = re.compile(".\t\d+.*")

        # loop through lines and find title line and line with coordinates

        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            # get title line
            if line.startswith('Freehand'):
                dict_roi['title'].append(line) 

                # initiate empty list per set
                XX = []  
                YY = []

            # line with coordinates starts with .\t
            # if pattern matches and line starts with .\t, get the coordinates
            for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
                if line.startswith('.\t'):
                    nln = "{}".format(line[2:].strip())
                    val = nln.split('{:6.1f}')

                    # data-massaging to get to the coordinates
                    for v in val:
                        coordinates_list = v.split("\t") 
                        for c in coordinates_list:
                            x, y = c.split(',')
                            print(x, y)
                            XX.append(float(x))
                            YY.append(float(y))

                        # this should append one list per set
                        dict_roi['X'].append(XX)
                        dict_roi['Y'].append(YY)


    except ValueError:
        print("Exiting")

    print(dict_roi)
```

Ideally, I would like to have an ordered dict which would give me something like:

```py
('X', [[104326.2, 104309.6, 104286.3, 104269.6, 104256.3, 104239.7, 104223.0, 104209.7, 104193.1, 104176.4], 
[99803.4, 99826.7, 99843.3, 99860.0, 99876.6]])

('Y', [[38323.8, 38307.2, 38287.3, 38270.6, 38254.0, 38237.4, 38220.7, 38204.1, 38194.1, 38187.5], 
[37296.2, 37306.2, 37312.8, 37316.2, 37322.8]])])
```

But my output looks like this:

```py
('X', [[104326.2, 104309.6, 104286.3, 104269.6, 104256.3, 104239.7, 104223.0, 104209.7, 104193.1, 104176.4], 
[104326.2, 104309.6, 104286.3, 104269.6, 104256.3, 104239.7, 104223.0, 104209.7, 104193.1, 104176.4], 
[99803.4, 99826.7, 99843.3, 99860.0, 99876.6]])

('Y', [[38323.8, 38307.2, 38287.3, 38270.6, 38254.0, 38237.4, 38220.7, 38204.1, 38194.1, 38187.5], 
[38323.8, 38307.2, 38287.3, 38270.6, 38254.0, 38237.4, 38220.7, 38204.1, 38194.1, 38187.5], 
[37296.2, 37306.2, 37312.8, 37316.2, 37322.8]])])
```

I get multiple copies of the list from the each of the set. For example, here the `X` and `Y` lists are duplicated from the first set. Probably it is something to do with clearing the lists after appending, or placement of the empty lists `XX` and `YY`. But I have tried multiple times with multiple variations and seem to get the output as above or a list per line instead of list per set in the ordered dict.

Does anyone have any idea how to format this code in a way that I get the output as mentioned in the ideal case?

Comment: Hi, your result and expected result are hard to diff.

Comment: Please show a *minimal* example. At least give us a smaller file to work with

Comment: Also, problem is here: `dict_roi['X'].append(XX)`. You keep appending the same list inject over and over

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how much more minimum I could go. The text file consists of basically 100s of lines and I have added just the first two lines.

Comment: @Tim basically, the same set of X and Y are appended twice :(

Comment: @MadPhysicist I see. Is there a way to refresh the lists in a way or append to the dictionary at a certain point that I get what I would like?

Comment: @Tim I tried to make the output little bit more readable now. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Make a new list every time. Multiple references to the same object see the same object.

Comment: I am not sure your question ask for a code optimization, please also reformulate the title :) Did you try @MadPhysicist suggestion by the way?

Comment: @Tim thanks for the suggestions. And no I did not understand what @MadPhysicist meant because I thought it is already happening every time the condition `if line.startswith('Freehand')` is satisfied. Should I move it into one of the inner loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified it slightly by not using a regular expression.

Instead, for each line the coordinates are stored in a list named `coords`.
Each x will have an even index, and y will be odd.
Thus, slicing this list will give you your `XX` and `YY`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

input_text = '''Freehand    green   2   2   0,0 289618  .   
.   104326.2,38323.8    104309.6,38307.2    104286.3,38287.3    104269.6,38270.6    104256.3,38254.0
.   104239.7,38237.4    104223.0,38220.7    104209.7,38204.1    104193.1,38194.1    104176.4,38187.5

Freehand    green   2   3   0,0 63980   .   
.   99803.4,37296.2 99826.7,37306.2 99843.3,37312.8 99860.0,37316.2 99876.6,37322.8'''


dict_roi = OrderedDict([('title', []),
                        ('X', []),
                        ('Y', [])])

lines = input_text.split('\n')

Xs = []
Ys = []

for i, line in enumerate(lines):

    # When a line contains a tile
    if line.startswith('Freehand'):
        dict_roi['title'].append(line)

        if Xs and Ys:
            dict_roi['X'].append(Xs)
            dict_roi['Y'].append(Ys)
            Xs = []
            Ys = []

    # When a line is empty
    elif not line:
        continue

    # When a line contains coordinates
    else:
        line = line.replace('\n', '')
        line = line.replace('\t', ',')
        line = line.replace(' ', ',')
        coords = line.split(',')
        coords = [e for e in coords if e != '.' and e]
        coords = [float(c) for c in coords]

        # Xs are even, Ys are odd
        Xs += coords[0:: 2]
        Ys += coords[1:: 2]

dict_roi['X'].append(Xs)
dict_roi['Y'].append(Ys)

print(dict_roi)
```

Output:

```
[('title', ['Freehand    green   2   2   0,0 289618  .   ', 'Freehand    green   2   3   0,0 63980   .   ']),

 ('X', [[104326.2, 104309.6, 104286.3, 104269.6, 104256.3, 104239.7, 104223.0, 104209.7, 104193.1, 104176.4], [99803.4, 99826.7, 99843.3, 99860.0, 99876.6]]), 

('Y', [[38323.8, 38307.2, 38287.3, 38270.6, 38254.0, 38237.4, 38220.7, 38204.1, 38194.1, 38187.5], [37296.2, 37306.2, 37312.8, 37316.2, 37322.8]])])
```

Comment: Hi Max! Thank you for the snippet! But there is a slight problem here. I would like all the coordinates from a single 'set' in one list. And I can see that it still creates a list of lists from I see one list per line in the file. :( Basically, all the x's from 104326.2 to  104176.4 has to go into one list and similarly for y.

Comment: Hi gaya! The snippet should work now. If you want to keep the coordinates for each 'set' in a list, you append the coordinates whenever you see a new set (or at the end of the file).

Comment: Hey again! With slight modifications I am able to get what I want :) Thank you! If I have your permission, I can add the edits to your answer and mark as accepted :D